# what is type of wallet with 18 words seed?

Tags: wallet, wallet-recovery

1) I have 18 words seed

> spray inject... (18 worlds total)

2) And i have some password/secret key or private key

> GVzPYhu....... (35 letters total)

What type of wallet and what crypto currency can there be access to?
I have already tried Electrum. Its dont work.
I'm ready to reward someone who will help.

Comment: Welcome @entarex11, no need to offer rewards, this site volunteers help for free.

Answer (score 1):

### 18-word phrase

I believe [Coinomi](https://www.coinomi.com/recovery-phrase-tool.html) was a wallet which would accept an 18-word seed phrase. There will be many others.

Coinomi lets you choose the length of your seed-phrase from a list of valid lengths: 3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24

### 35 random letters

Private keys are usually longer

Addresses can be 35 letters long but usually start with a digit or with `bc1`

See https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes

Perhaps this is a passphrase for the seed-phrase - the BIP39 specification allows for an optional passphrase. Some wallets have an "option" button which may allow you to enter a BIP39 passphrase - though they may call it a "seed extension" or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Could be an old blockchain.info recovery mnemonic. You can try to recover access [here](https://login.blockchain.com/wallet/forgot-password). You will also need your wallet UUID to login. Look for that in your email archive.

Answer (score -1):

Usually HD wallets like Coinomi are used to take backup of multiple cryptos.  A mnemonic code or sentence is superior for human interaction compared to the handling of raw binary or hexadecimal representations of a wallet seed.

### Generating the mnemonic

---

The mnemonic must encode entropy in a multiple of 32 bits. With more entropy security is improved but the sentence length increases. We refer to the initial entropy length as ENT. The allowed size of ENT is 128-256 bits.

First, an initial entropy of ENT bits is generated. A checksum is generated by taking the first

```
ENT / 32
```

bits of its SHA256 hash. This checksum is appended to the end of the initial entropy. Next, these concatenated bits are split into groups of 11 bits, each encoding a number from 0-2047, serving as an index into a wordlist. Finally, we convert these numbers into words and use the joined words as a mnemonic sentence.

The following table describes the relation between the initial entropy length (ENT), the checksum length (CS) and the length of the generated mnemonic sentence (MS) in words.

```
CS = ENT / 32
MS = (ENT + CS) / 11

|  ENT  | CS | ENT+CS |  MS  |
+-------+----+--------+------+
|  128  |  4 |   132  |  12  |
|  160  |  5 |   165  |  15  |
|  192  |  6 |   198  |  18  |
|  224  |  7 |   231  |  21  |
|  256  |  8 |   264  |  24  |
```

Comment: The question was "what type of wallet uses an 18-word seed". An answer would be a list of the names of wallet software which match that criterion. You seem to have answered a different question